# How can a 'scripts' directory be hooked into wp_head();?

Tags: php, theme-development, wp-head

So I'm trying to get my head round `<?php wp_head(); ?>`.

I understand that it loads in the stuff needed for plugins etc., but I'm using a theme that seems to be using it to load in scripts for theme elements as well.

There's a folder within my theme called 'scripts' that appears to have all of the javascript needed for the theme. In the outputted code is all of the javascript files etc.

So my question is: How do I hook in a javascript file (or anything for that matter) into `<?php wp_head(); ?>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for Javascript files in your theme `functions.php` files. I suggest wrapping up all the requests in a function and hook it like so

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_enqueuer' );
```

Comment: Ok so I'm looking at the pinboard theme and in this is what it's doing: 
`add_action( 'init', 'pinboard_register_scripts' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'pinboard_enqueue_scripts' ) ) :
function pinboard_enqueue_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'ios-orientationchange-fix' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'fitvids' );`

Can't I just add in a new script like `wp_enqueue_script( 'example' );` to that list? I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can. But if you want to call it just by the name, you have to register the script using [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)